# Convert Number to digits in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, nsnumber

I have received duration from service. the duration is 0.73
so i have tried this

```
if (value >= 1.0 && value < 60.0) {
    double value = 0.73;
    double d = value * 1000;
    NSLog(@"milli seconds = %03d ms",(int)d);
    //Output is 730ms    --> which is correct. 
}
```

If i received 1.45 above 1.0

```
double value = 1.45
if (value >= 1.0 && value < 60.0) {
    double d = value * 1000;
    double sec = (int)value % 60;
    NSLog(@"%02d s:%012.f ms",(int)sec, d);
    //Output is 01 s: 000000001450 ms
}


The output should be as 01s:450ms
```

I need to change this to 01s:450ms. but i cant try this. any body help this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use NSDateComponentsFormatter are write a custom formatter

Comment: @phix23 I understood. but how can i get the expected result. I need to remove first number in the integer. can you give any reference

Comment: That's a lot of work for an `NSLog()` call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double value = 1.45;
if (value >= 1.0 && value < 60.0) {    
    double sec = (int)value % 60;
    double d = (value - sec) * 1000;
    NSLog(@"%02ds:%.0f ms",(int)sec, d);
}
```

Comment: & ABao answer both is correct. whose answer i accept. :P

Comment: Both Are Same so it doesn't matter! He answer First and its depend upon You!

Answer (score 4):

%012.f means that you want your answer to always have 12 places with 0 padding for those places. To change it to what you have written you can do

```
NSLog(@"%02ds:%03.0f ms",(int)sec, d);
```

This will print the milliseconds number with no decimal places so if you have 1.4566 you will end up with `01s:457ms`. Is this what you were after?

You can find out loads more about string formatting by looking up the man page for `printf` on a *nix machine go to terminal and type man printf.

Comment: the output is "01s:1450 ms". expected o/p is 01s:450 ms.  I need to remove 1 from 1450 ms

Comment: Then you need to do double `double  d = (value - floor (value)) * 1000;` when you make d. This gets only the fractional part of the value.

Comment: Your code is now working. But i accepted another answer due to he have less points for increase his points.

Comment: You may want to check that you get the right result for 1.045, as you may need the `03` in `%03.0f` for it to print what you want.

Comment: Yeah. working correctly as per your instruction. great.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
   double value = 1.45;

    if (value >= 1.0 && value < 60.0) {
        int sec = (int)value;
        int minisecond = value*1000 - sec*1000;
        NSLog(@"%02d s:%3d ms",(int)sec, minisecond);
        //Output is 01 s:450 ms
    }
```

Comment: & Saurabh Prajapati answer both is correct. whose answer i accept. :P

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is answered. But people who are curious to use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`

```
class customFormatter: NSDateComponentsFormatter {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

     convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    override func stringForObjectValue(obj: AnyObject) -> String? {

        if(obj.isKindOfClass(NSNumber.classForCoder()))
        {
            var whole = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(obj.integerValue)
            var fractional : Float
            fractional = modff(obj.floatValue, whole)
            return "\( obj.floatValue - fractional )s \(fractional * 1000)ms"
        }
        return "Bad Input Type"
    }


}

let formatter = customFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Abbreviated
let number = 10.4
let string = formatter.stringForObjectValue(number)
```